# Change spacing before and after (sub)sections in KOMA class

Tags: koma-script, titlesec, titleps

This is my first time using `LaTeX` and I want to reduce the space below subsubsections (and others). Similar questions have been asked multiple times, and the solution was usually to use `titlesec`.

I use this "template":

```
\documentclass[%
    enabledeprecatedfontcommands,
    oneside,        % Einseitiger Druck.
    12pt,           % Schriftgroesse
    parskip=half,   % Halbe Zeile Abstand zwischen Absätzen.
    headsepline,    % Linie nach Kopfzeile.
    footsepline,    % Linie vor Fusszeile.
    abstracton,     % Abstract Überschriften
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{main}{
  \setheadrule{0.4pt}% Header rule
  \setfootrule{.4pt}% Footer rule
  \sethead[\documentnumber~Rev.~\currentrevision]% odd-left
          []% odd-center
          [\chaptertitle]% odd-right
          {\chaptertitle}% even-left
          {}% even-center
          {}
    \setfoot[]% odd-left
          []% odd-center
          [\thepage]% odd-right
          {}% even-left
          {\thepage}% even-center
          {}% even-right
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{Declaration of Authorship}
lalala

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
    
\pagestyle{main}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{chapter1}
\section{Section1}
Text
\subsection{SubSection1}
Text
\subsubsection{SubSubSection1}
Text
\subsubsection{SubSubSection2}
Text
\end{document}
```

And get this result:

[image]

The space below headings is too much. As other answers suggest using `titlesec`, I tried it. I receive many errors. Apparently `titleps` and `titlesec` don't work well together, but loading `titlesec` like this (and not loading `titleps` separately): `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}` should work ([as stated here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276029/package-titlesec-error-incompatible-package)).

For me, it doesn't (overleaf shows a total of 20 errors):
[image]
[image]

How can I lower the spacing without `titlesec`?

Comment: It seems you didn't use the `\titleformat` command for subsubsections. On another, the `titlesec` package also has a `\titlespacing` command, for spacing above and spacing below.

Comment: Yes I didn't even get to using it, as the \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} broke the whole document. I think this needs to be fixed beforehand, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using KOMA-Script, I suggest using its built-in commands. In your case:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0pt]{subsubsection}
```

Obviously, this works similarly from `{chapter}` all the way down to `{subparagraph}`. Using `\RedeclareSectionCommands` (note the plural -s) you can even provide multiple values at a time:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[% Command*s*, plural
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=-1ex]{paragraph,subparagraph}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I use this template from my university and prior to your answer, I didn't even know about KOMA-Script. I just found out that the header can also be adjusted using some KOMA-Script stuff, so I could also get rid of titleps :)